# How to remove submit parameters after appending them dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, form-submit

I have a form and I need to append two items that are not in the form scope. I'm using jQuery to do it.

My code is working, however, the second time that I submit the form, I'm getting the values I selected in the first time.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnUpdate").click(function (event) {

            var items = [];

            $('#params :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                items[i] = $(selected).text();
                $(selected).prop("selected", false)
            });

            //So far, so good. My variable 'items' changes the second time.

            //The problem is here:

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                var submitVal = items[i];
                $('#myForm').append("<input type='hidden' name='param" + i + "' value='" + submitVal + "' />");
            }

            return true;
        });
    });

</script>
```

I guess the second time I'm appending a third and a fourth parameters, which means that I have `param0, param1` - from the first time - and `param0, param1` again - from the second time.

In the third time I'm appending a fifth and sixth and so on.

On the server side I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

```
public ActionResult Method(string param0 = "", string param1 = "")
```

I tried to use the method `.submit` but I was not successful, that is why I'm using the `.click` method.

Now I'm trying to append the two parameters, submit the form, and remove them after.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Or any ideas to a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any other hidden inputs in your form, you could try removing them all before adding the new items:

```
$('#myForm').find('input[type=hidden]').remove(); //remove all hidden elements

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var submitVal = items[i];
    $('#myForm').append("<input type='hidden' name='param" + i + "' value='" + submitVal + "' />");
}
```

If you have other hidden elements, tag these dynamic ones with the same class and use that to select the elements to remove:

```
$('#myForm').find('input[type=hidden].dynamic').remove(); //remove all hidden elements tagged with dynamic class

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var submitVal = items[i];
    $('#myForm').append("<input class='dynamic' type='hidden' name='param" + i + "' value='" + submitVal + "' />");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would spend a bit more effort getting this to work with the submit event, since the user doesn't necessarily need to click the button to submit the form.

But anyway, I would give the dynamically added inputs a special class, and use that to remove them on page load:

```
$('#myForm').append("<input type='hidden' class='dynamically-added' name='param" + i + "' value='" + submitVal + "' />");
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.dynamically-added').remove();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. However, I will try to work with the submit event as soon as I have more time to work on this. Thank you.